# How to drag and drop external files in C++/WinRT WinUI3?

Tags: drag-and-drop, winui-3, c++-winrt, winui

I saw the same problem, but the author did not provide a solution.

I am sure that all methods are the same as that problem, and all processes are using the Administrator.

But it doesn't work, dragging the file still shows X

Reference:  [How to drag and drop external files into WinUI3 apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77298989/)

this is a example.

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Window x:Class="App1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="using:App1"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Border Width="300" Height="300"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" AllowDrop="True"
            Background="Pink" CanDrag="True"
            DragEnter="Border_DragEnter"
            DragLeave="Border_DragLeave"
            DragOver="Border_DragOver"
            DragStarting="Border_DragStarting"
            Drop="Border_Drop">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Drop files here!" />
    </Border>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cpp

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainWindow.xaml.h"
#if __has_include("MainWindow.g.cpp")
#include "MainWindow.g.cpp"
#endif

#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.h>

namespace winrt::App1::implementation {
    Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainWindow::Border_Drop(IInspectable const&, DragEventArgs const& e) {
        if (e.DataView().Contains(Windows::ApplicationModel::DataTransfer::StandardDataFormats::StorageItems())) {
            Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<Windows::Storage::IStorageItem> items
                = co_await e.DataView().GetStorageItemsAsync();
            for (auto item : items) {
                auto file = item.as<Windows::Storage::StorageFile>();
                OutputDebugStringW(file.Path().data());
            }
        }
    }

    void MainWindow::Border_DragOver(IInspectable const&, DragEventArgs const& e) {
        OutputDebugStringW(L"DragOver\n");
        e.AcceptedOperation(Windows::ApplicationModel::DataTransfer::DataPackageOperation::Copy);
    }

    void MainWindow::Border_DragEnter(IInspectable const&, DragEventArgs const& e) {
        OutputDebugStringW(L"DragEnter\n");
    }

    void MainWindow::Border_DragLeave(IInspectable const&, DragEventArgs const& e) {
        OutputDebugStringW(L"DragLeave\n");
    }

    void MainWindow::Border_DragStarting(UIElement const&, DragStartingEventArgs const&) {
        OutputDebugStringW(L"DragStarting\n");
    }
}
```

I have listened to almost all the events, and the current issue is not data acquisition, but displaying prohibition symbols during drag and drop. I am unable to complete the drag and drop at all.

I see another question that is related to Windows preferences, but I haven't found the specific content yet.

I saw others saying it was an issue with running the program as an administrator. But my app and Windows Explorer are both running as administrators, so there should be no permission issues. And for some Microsoft apps, even when running as an administrator, they can still be dragged and dropped, not only my app.

---

I tried using hook to capture native **WM_DROPFILES** message, After setting the extension style **WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES** through **SetWindowLong**. I can drag and drop it now. I don't know if the implementation of WinUI3 has blocked messages or does not allow drag and drop of files

Comment: Actually, there was no solution because there was no reproducing project, please provide one: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: For more details about how to implement drag and drop, you could refer to the Doc: [Drag and drop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/drag-and-drop)

Comment: Sorry, I have added some content. Could you please take a look again

Comment: Not your issue, but passing references into coroutines is a memory corruption waiting to happen. For coroutines you will always want to pass by value.

Comment: I've tested your code and it show OutputDebugString traces fine, and drop works fine too. Your statement about your app *and* explorer running as administrator is a bit strange and a bad smell. Are you 100% sure about that?

Comment: I have read many related questions and they all say that there is no problem reproducing, but I cannot do it. All of my events cannot be triggered because when I drag a file into the window boundary, a prohibited symbol is displayed, even if I change my computer. I want to know if it's due to permission issues. My current user is administrator

Comment: It's not because your user is an administrator that any .exe on your desktop runs "as administrator". I'm running as admin too but UAC is on (as it should be), and Explorer does *not* run as administrator. You should provide a reproducing sample, but it ultimately sounds like a deployment issue, not a code issue;